# Min sdk api for Eddystone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone

I know Android 4.3.1 (API 18) introduced built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy. But the new open BLE standard from Google aka Eddystone, what is min SDK version to develop for this new standard or does the new multi-beacon frame not influence the min sdk?

Answer (score 1):

A device needs to have Android 4.3+ with Bluetooth LE in order to work with Eddystone.  That doesn't necessarily mean the min SDK for your app has to be API 18 -- it just means Bluetooth LE features like Eddystone cannot be used if the device does not have API 18.

The above is true with using the free and open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) to [detect Eddystone](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html).  You can read more about how to make an app work with backward compatible devices [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/backward-compatibility.html)  Google also has sample apps using their proprietary SDKs, but they all require Android 5.1.